# asp .net MVC application not recognising [Key, Column(Order = 0)] attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;    

public class UserArmy
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public int UnitId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is a model class I have. I'm using the Entity Framework, Code First approach. The [Key] attribute is recognised but not the Column(Order=x).

Am I missing something that needs to be included?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add following namespace:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.aspx

Comment: perfect thanks, I thought the thing I was 'using' would cover all I needed but they have to make it so complex! lol